# Air conditioner not cycling, always running, engine fans always on, using more fuel

Tags: ford, ac, climate-control

I have a 2010 Ford Territory that has developed a climate control issue that I'm having a hard time trying to diagnose myself.

**Here's a description of the problem:**

When you start the car with the climate control set to auto, the compressor immediately clicks on regardless of the cabin temperature. Within about 5-10 seconds, the engine thermo fan cuts in and remains on until you manually turn the air conditioner off - after which the thermo fan remains on for a minute or so. Usually, the air conditioner would cycle on and off in response to the cabin temperature - but in this case it comes on and stays on. The engine is also noticeably under load and we've seen an increase in fuel consumption. I should also mention that the thermo fan kicks in even when the engine is cold.

Another issue which could be related is that recently the cabin blower fan has been intermittently failing to start. The ICC shows the fan as running and it responds to controls, you can hear the HVAC cycling through different modes - just no air. Usually it will come on given enough time; sometimes it comes on straight away, sometimes 30 seconds or so, sometimes we could be waiting 5 minutes - it's fairly random. Could this be the blower motor resistor going?

**Information I have so far:**

- There are no error codes from the engine computer
- All fuses are intact and powered
- All temperature readings from the computer look normal

Comment: Is the cabin temperature sensor blocked / obstructed / faulty?

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm going to have to check into that. It is entirely possible I obstructed it while I had the dash off while running some wires a few months back. I wish I was able to read the values off the unit, but unfortunately I only have and ODB-II reader and can't look at the CAN bus with my gear. I guess I'll be taking the dash apart again :)